# oracle sql navigator data-mining text-mining

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

how can i search lets say `FORMULA_TEXT` field in a database where in between start and the end character of `'`  we have `#` or `@`

for example `@A'123'HEY'345''@B'K`

SO in this example we have `123` , `345` and `@B` in between start and the end of `'` character so i want to find these with sql. lets say in each record i have this `FORMULA_TEXT` filed and i will check if it contains `@` or `#` in between start and the and of `'` character.

So in my example result is `@B`

By the way if its too hard I can first find `@`s and then `#`s which are in between start and end `'` character

ps: `HEY` is not in between start and the end of ' character in my example.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions150.htm#i1239858):

```
SQL> SELECT txt, regex, regexp_substr(txt, regex, 1, 1, 'c', '3') result
  2    FROM (SELECT q'¤@A'123'HEY'345''@B'K¤' txt,
  3                 q'¤^([^']*|('[^']*')*?)*?'([^']*[@#][^']*)'¤' regex
  4            FROM dual);

TXT                  REGEX                                    RESULT
-------------------- ---------------------------------------- ---------
@A'123'HEY'345''@B'K ^([^']*|('[^']*')*?)*?'([^']*[@#][^']*)' @B
```